# A service when run as Local Service gets stopped in Windows 2008

Tags: windows, java, services, windows-services

A service associated with a Java application deployed in my system runs fine when it is running with Local System account but I want to run it with Local Service.

I changed from Local System account to Local Service (services.msc -> service Properties -> Log on -> This account: -> NT AUTHORITY\LocalService)

The service is getting start but it stops in no time.
With Local System account the service runs fine.

Any guess how can I make this service go running with Local Service?

OS: Windows 2008

Answer (score 0):

Have you found any information in Event Viewer, especially looking under System log for sources under Service Control Manager and the Security log? That’s a good start if not. Can this application run under this account as well?